# How to remove the Edge label from a DSE Graph using gremlin console

Tags: datastax-enterprise, gremlin-server, datastax-enterprise-graph

How to remove the `Edge label` from a

> DataStax Enterprise 5.0 Graph

using

> gremlin console

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply looking to drop an edge by its Id:

```
g.E(edge_id).drop()
```

If you are looking to drop all edges that have a certain label

```
g.E().hasLabel('example_label').drop()
```

This makes two assumptions. First, that you have assigned g as the alias for the the graph you want to interact with.

```
 :remote config alias g graph_name.g
```

Second: Unless you have turned on development mode for your graph, you will need to setup the appropriate indexes for your EdgeLabel. By Default deep scans of a graph aren't allowed for performance reasons and proper indexing helps prevent those types of scans.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/graph/using/indexOverview.html